# Why isn't Subaru allowed to tell anyone about his "return by death" power?

Tags: re-zero

In Re:Zero, Subaru has the "return by death" power, but when he tries to tell anyone about it he is stopped by what I assume is "The Witch". Why does this happen? Why can't Subaru tell anyone about his power?

Comment: He is allowed, he just can't bear the suffering it brings as soon as he tries :)

Comment: well thats what i mean, why does the witch try to stop him?

Comment: Anime still hasn't revealed that, but you may try your luck reading manga.

Comment: Apparently, this was not covered yet even in novel. But it seems, that witch doesn't want anyone to know about this ability of Subaru. When Subaru was able to Emilia about this, witch directly destroyed Emilia's heart.

Comment: My guess it ia because Subaru will be the recipient, and not Emilia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The witch seems to have given him his Return by Death power and stops him when he tries to reveal it. The witch's motivations for giving him the power or keeping it secret have not been revealed yet. It seems pretty clear that there's no way for Subaru to overcome the witch and reveal the power -- when he tried to overpower the witch and reveal his ability to Emilia, the witch killed Emilia.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest key lies in the role of the witch - the witch of **Envy**. She is altogether not at all keen on him sharing just about anything with others, but most especially anything he shares with her.